# how can i access nested services call json API data in angular7 using observables?

Tags: service, angular7

I made a project to pull data from web service API. But the web service has nested arrays that needs to be displayed too, how can i access the data from nested JSON arrays?, what is the right way to write inside the HTML to get the data from the web service. By the way when i fetch the first objects it shows correctly, only in the nested objects.

I made a project to pull data from web service API. But the web service has nested arrays that needs to be displayed too, how can i access the data from nested JSON arrays?, what is the right way to write inside the HTML to get the data from the web service. By the way when i fetch the first objects it shows correctly, only in the nested objects.
[enter image description here][1]

```
{
"$id": "1",
"result": null,
"error": false,
"message": "worked succesfully",
"dataArray": [
    {
        "$id": "2",
        "courseImage": "http://localhost:54615/courseImage/Biology.png",
        "courseName": "Biology",
        "courseDet": [
            {
                "$id": "3",
                "addedtime": "Just Now",
                "courseDetName": "download bialogy paper",
                "courseDetCode": "b-382"
            },
            {
                "$id": "4",
                "addedtime": "11:23 PM",
                "courseDetName": "submit a test paper for checking",
                "courseDetCode": ""
            },
            {
                "$id": "5",
                "addedtime": "08:20 PM",
                "courseDetName": "attend a test",
                "courseDetCode": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "$id": "6",
        "courseImage": "http://localhost:54615/courseImage/Biology.png",
        "courseName": "Chemistry",
        "courseDet": [
            {
                "$id": "7",
                "addedtime": "Just Now",
                "courseDetName": "download bialogy paper",
                "courseDetCode": "b-382"
            },
            {
                "$id": "8",
                "addedtime": "11:23 PM",
                "courseDetName": "submit a test paper for checking",
                "courseDetCode": ""
            },
            {
                "$id": "9",
                "addedtime": "08:20 PM",
                "courseDetName": "attend a test",
                "courseDetCode": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "$id": "10",
        "courseImage": "http://localhost:54615/courseImage/Biology.png",
        "courseName": "Physics",
        "courseDet": [
            {
                "$id": "11",
                "addedtime": "Just Now",
                "courseDetName": "download bialogy paper",
                "courseDetCode": "b-382"
            },
            {
                "$id": "12",
                "addedtime": "11:23 PM",
                "courseDetName": "submit a test paper for checking",
                "courseDetCode": ""
            },
            {
                "$id": "13",
                "addedtime": "08:20 PM",
                "courseDetName": "attend a test",
                "courseDetCode": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}
**courseinfo.ts**

```
export class Coursepost {
result: string;
error:string;
message:string;
dataArray:[];
```

}

**courseinfo.service.ts**

```
getAboutPosts() {
return this.http.post('',"");
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Acecess nested data, you will need to loop over your array and write the data to the screen.

Set the response from the API to a new instance of your Object model and then in HTMl you need to Loop over your items in your nested array, you will need 3 models to match the incoming data like so

```
export class Object{
    $id: number;
    result: string;
    error: string;
    message: string;
    dataArray: data[];
}

export class data{
    $id: number;
    courseImage: string;
    courseName: string;
    courseDet: courseInfo[];
}

export class courseInfo{
    $id: number;
    addedtime: datetime;
    courseDetName: string;
    courseDetCode: string;
}
```

Then you need to loop over all the objects like so

```
<div *ngFor="let data of Object.dataArray">

   <p>{{data.courseName}}</p>
   <p>{{data.courseImage}}</p>

   <div *ngFor="let course of data.courseDet"> 
      <p>{{course.addedtime}}</p>
      <p>{{course.courseDetName}}</p>
      <p>{{course.courseDetCode}}</p>
   </div>

</div>
```

Syntax may not be perfect as I am writing from memory however the output should be something like

```
Biology
<img>
download biology paper
submit a test paper for checking
attend a test

Chemistry
<img>
download biology paper
submit a test paper for checking
attend a test

Physics
<img>
download biology paper
submit a test paper for checking
attend a test
```

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please feel free to up vote it, thanks